# Fields in monoidal categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

We can speak of [rings in monoidal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ring+object), including also [the non-Cartesian case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397698). What about fields?

---

### Question 1: Definitions

> What are some possible notions of a (skew or commutative) field in a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$?

So far, I've found the following:

- **Approach #1:** Taking the point of view of fields as rings where nonzero elements have inverses, one could start by considering groups of units, as done in the nLab page on [topological fields](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+field#internalization).
- **Approach #2:** Viewing fields representation-theoretically, we could define a field in $\mathcal{C}$ to be a ring object $k$ such that every $k$-module in $\mathcal{C}$ is (isomorphic to a) free one.
- **Approach #3:** The notion of an ideal makes sense in any "nice" monoidal category; see Section 4.2 of [Martin brandenburg's PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716). One could define a field in $\mathcal{C}$ as a ring object $k$ in $\mathcal{C}$ having only $k$ and $(0)$ as ideals.

How do these approaches compare to each other? What are other possible definitions?

---

### Question 2: Examples

Finally, what are some examples of fields in monoidal categories? In particular:

- When $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Top}$, the first approach above recovers topological fields (i.e. topological rings $k$ which are fields but also whose inverse map $a\mapsto a^{-1}$ defines a *continuous* map $(-)^{-1}\colon k^{\times}\to k^{\times}$). Do the other approaches recover this continuity condition too?
- For $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Sch}$, we have a well-studied notion of a ring scheme, of which a very important example is the ring scheme $\mathbb{W}$ of Witt vectors (for an introduction,  see [Eric's translation of Grothendieck's Groupes de Barsotti–Tate et Cristaux de Dieudonné](https://chromotopy.org/latex/misc/cristaux-eng.pdf)). What are some examples of *field schemes*?
- For $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{CCoAlg}_{R}$, rings in $\mathcal{C}$ give the notion of a Hopf ring. What are examples of *Hopf fields*?

Comment: I don't believe that there will be a singular "the" correct notion.

Comment: I like division algebra meaning A-mod is semisimple and A is simple as an A-mod, so that you get an Artin-Wedderbern theorem for semisimple algebra objects.  You could say it's a field if it's endowed with a lift to the center making it commutative, but I'm not sure how natural or useful that is.  Part of me wants to say it's a mistake to try to talk about commutativity unless you're in a braided category.

Comment: There are already some non-equivalent definitions of internal fields in topoi, which is just a special case of the Cartesian case. So I agree with Theo's comment.

Comment: There is an essential difference between rings and fields that does not seem to have been recognised in the question or answers: there is an **exclusive disjunction** between zero and invertible elements. To express this you need a category that is **extensive** (has stable disjoint coproducts) as well as having a monoidal structure.

Answer (score 8):

In the stable homotopy category, it is standard to define a *field spectrum* to be a ring spectrum $F$ such that every nonzero homogeneous element of the graded homotopy ring $\pi_*(F)$ is invertible.  This ensures that every $F$-module spectrum is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i\in I}\Sigma^{d_i}F$ for some indexing set $I$ and some system of degrees $d_i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For each prime $p$ and integer $n>0$ there is a Morava $K$-theory spectrum $K(p,n)$ with $\pi_*(K(p,n))=(\mathbb{Z}/p)[v_n,v_n^{-1}]$ with $|v_n|=2(p^n-1)$.  Additionally, we have the Eilenberg-MacLane spectra $K(p,\infty)=H\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $K(0)=H\mathbb{Q}$.  These are all field spectra.  It is an important theorem that in a certain sense (not quite the most obvious one) this is a complete list of the prime field spectra.  All of these examples are commutative except in the case $p=2$ where instead we have a rule like $ab-ba=v_nQ_n(a)Q_n(b)$ for a certain operation $Q_n$ with $Q_n^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks! (Incidentally, the case of field spectra was what made me think of this question in the first place!)

Answer (score 4):

Paul Balmer, Henning Krause, and Greg Stevenson [have](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02167v2) investigated the concept of 'field' in tensor-triangulated geometry (see Definition 1.1).