# Has this notion of a ring in a bimonoidal category been studied before?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, semirings

The [Baez–Dolan microcosm principle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/microcosm+principle) is stated in the nLab as follows.

> **Microcosm principle:** Certain algebraic structures can be defined in any category equipped with a categorified version of the same structure.

Recently I noticed that, while we can define rings in monoidal categories (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397698/examples-of-rings-in-monoidal-categories) for  examples) via a somewhat contrived construction, there's a much simpler notion of a semiring in a semiring category, [detailed in the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ring+object#ViaTheMicrocosmPrinciple), with [examples](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ring+object#examples).

**Question.** Has this notion been defined/studied before in the literature?

---

**Edit.** Yes, it partially appeared in Definition 5.1 in

> Morten Brun, *Witt Vectors and Equivariant Ring Spectra*, 2006. Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 94, pp. 351–385. ([arXiv:math/0411567](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411567), [doi:10.1112/plms/pdl010](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/pdl010).)

but somewhat quickly. Are there other references?

Comment: All your examples have $\oplus= $ coproduct, so that the additive monoid structure trivializes. Do you have examples in mind where it doesn't ?

Comment: There's also a page on 2-rigs -- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-rig -- which presents a range of variants.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Currently, no :/ (besides trivial ones like $0$ with the trivial morphisms in $\mathbb{F}$, $\mathbb{S}$, or $R_{\mathsf{disc}}$ for $R$ a ring). In fact, I think I don't know many semiring categories with $\oplus\neq$ coproduct at all! I've asked about this in a separate question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403087), after failing to come up with any useful examples...

Comment: This notion appears also here (and in more generality!): https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colax-distributive+rig+category.